# Getting a url for for subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials

Tags: node.js, html, http, cloudant

I am using Cloudant for uploading and getting back images. Cloudant uses basic auth to validate users for reading images. Now I want to make a picture gallery by getting back all the images stored in cloudant and I am planning to use  tags with the url for images stored in cloudant. If I use img src="https://username:password@myapp-bluemix.cloudant.com/db/docName/attachment_name I am getting the following error
[Url containing embedded credentials are blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKWwH.jpg)

Is there a way to get a signed url for this as is possible in S3 so that I can use it in my img tags as src?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856) is preventing a URL containing embedded credentials being fetched from with a web page.

There is no way to create a pre-signed URL, as S3 has.

This leaves you with a few options:

- make the database "world readable", although this is probably not an option for you.
- deliver your images through a proxy - a "serverless" cloud function could be written that has read access to your Cloudant database and streams selected attachments in response to a web request.
- adopt a hybrid approach and store your image *meta data* in Cloudant but store the binary blobs in Object Storage, which is much better fit for storing data. Here is a blog post about [detaching attachments from Cloudant and storing them in Object Storage](https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/detaching-cloudant-attachments-to-object-storage-with-serverless-functions-99b8c3c77925) and another about [creating a pre-signed URL to allow their download](https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/keeping-your-secrets-between-cloud-object-storage-and-your-browser-part-2-3991e39e5403).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpful. I have one question though, is the S3 api open source and can I use it officially for developing projects for IBM? because IBM has strict policies when it comes to using third party api's.

Comment: IBM's Cloudant Object Storage has an partial S3-compatible API. See https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/hmac/credentials.html#using-hmac-credentials